# Trouble importing project Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project that I am trying to load into eclipse.

I was given a WAR file. I unzipped the WAR file and see there are 4 folders

.settings
build
resources
src    - contains java source code it appears
WebConent
.classpath
.project

How do I load this project into Eclipse? I see so many options to import this but not sure which method I Should do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.project` file is the one you can use to import in `Eclipse`. If the project has a `pom.xml` file (a `Maven` project) then you can import as "`Existing Maven Project`"

For Eclipse's `.project` file import - go to `Import` -> `General` -> `Existing Projects into Workspace` and select the `.project` file

Answer (score 0):

War file is not a valide project to open in using eclipse, the war file is a proyect commpiled